# WAMPSERVER Localhost Crashes and Apache variable '${INSTALL_DIR}' is not defined errors

Tags: localhost, wampserver, httpd.conf

So I get these errors.

1. Apache variable '${INSTALL_DIR}' is not defined
2. Locolhost crashes when launched via WAMP Control Panel but not when typed directly into address bar.

Below is the lines showing that the INSTALL_DIR directive is defined.
What am I doing wrong?

```
Define INSTALL_DIR c:/wamp64
Define APACHE_DIR ${INSTALL_DIR}/bin/apache/apache${VERSION_APACHE}
Define SRVROOT ${INSTALL_DIR}/bin/apache/apache${VERSION_APACHE}
ServerRoot "${SRVROOT}"*
```

Comment: Exactly where do you see this error and when doing exactly what

Comment: Did you make any changes to the `httpd.conf` file just before this started to happen?

Comment: Like did you add the `*` after this line? `ServerRoot "${SRVROOT}"*` if so remove it

Comment: The * was put there by mistake when learning how to format code on this post. Putting the directory in quotes helped with part and apache is running, but when I launch localhost from the wamp taskbar, I get page crashed. I can manually type in localhost into the browser and it works fine.

Comment: Maybe remove the * in your question then :-)

Answer (score 1):

Put the paths between quotes (and the asterisk after "${SRVROOT}" has to be removed) so like this:

```
Define INSTALL_DIR "c:/wamp64"
Define APACHE_DIR "${INSTALL_DIR}/bin/apache/apache${VERSION_APACHE}"
Define SRVROOT "${INSTALL_DIR}/bin/apache/apache${VERSION_APACHE}"
ServerRoot "${SRVROOT}"
```

Because both variables APACHE_DIR and SRVROOT are pointing to the same location, you can also do this:

```
Define INSTALL_DIR "c:/wamp64"
Define APACHE_DIR "${INSTALL_DIR}/bin/apache/apache${VERSION_APACHE}"
Define SRVROOT "${APACHE_DIR}"
ServerRoot "${SRVROOT}"
```

Or completely get rid of SRVROOT, but I think it's implemented in a lot of xampp files, so it's best not to remove that one :-)

Also a way to test your config is:
Navigate the Apache bin folder (in your case: c:\wamp64\bin\apache\apacheversionnumber\bin) in cmd (command prompt) and type: httpd -t and hit enter => you ask Apache to test your config, if there's an error, it'll tell you in which file at which line, otherwise it'll say: `Syntax OK`

Comment: Protip: You can also navigate to the bin-folder in the file explorer and type cmd in the path and hit enter, it will start a commandwindow in that directory.

Comment: Quotes are no necessary in this situation

Comment: **`xampp files`** Its a WAMPServer instance

Comment: I'm aware we're talking about WAMP... Windows, yes... Still, if there's a space in the path, you should use quotes, so why not be consistent and use it always?

Comment: There is no space! I use WAMPServer and that config works just Hunky Dory on 100's of instances. So this answer wont solve whatever is causing this guys issues

Comment: I know there's no space. I'm just saying that best practise is to use the quotes anyway. Arguing here isn't going to contribute to help get an answer for Chris...

Comment: Some parts of the answer might still fix his problem, like the asterisk after serverroot that needs to be removed, and maybe testing to see what apache error you get...

Comment: Nice steal on my answer with the * @RiggsFolly :-) Too bad I'm one point short to comment on the main topic :-P Anyway I'm out :-) Peace!

Comment: Its the only part that was in any way likely to be useful other than the test suggestion. Its not a steal, I was trying to emphasis that along with the other clarifications I asked

Comment: I followed instructions by RiggsFolly and it comes out saying "Syntax OK" which is good. My sites are up now, but when clicking on "Localhost" in the taskbar WAMP dashboard, I still get page crashed and like I mentioned above, I can manually type in localhost into the address bar and everything works fine. I just don't want to continue developing this server for multiple sites and end up with it crashing later.

Comment: @ChrisHarrison Probably a config error then in the xampp files somewhere. If you have an extra pc, install xampp on that one, copy all the files from c:\xampp to the main pc, and compare the files with https://winmerge.org, hopefully you can find the error like this.